# Bike rack : should I grease the tow ball?

Tags: grease, trailer-hitch

I have recently installed a towbar, and I plan to use it exclusively with a bike rack.

Should I grease the tow ball ?

Comment: Does you bike rack attach to a ball or does it slide into the receiver?

Comment: It attaches to a ball